# Telegram bot ConversationHandler ignores fallbacks

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I have an issue with the Telegram bot (python-telegram-bot). I've made ConversationHandler, but the "fallbacks" won't work. Bot just ignores the "/stop " command. When I send "/stop" the bot sends me "First handler" instead of "GoodBye". What's wrong?

```
import os

import telegram
from telegram.ext import (ConversationHandler,
                          CommandHandler,
                          MessageHandler,
                          Filters,
                          Updater
)
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

TELEGRAM_TOKEN = os.environ['TELEGRAM_TOKEN']
USER_ID = os.environ['USER_ID']
bot = telegram.Bot(token=TELEGRAM_TOKEN)
updater = Updater(token=TELEGRAM_TOKEN)


def start(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                             text='hi')
    return 1


def stop(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message('Good Bye')
    return ConversationHandler.END


def first_handler(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                             text='First handler')
    return 1


conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points=[CommandHandler('Start', start)],
    states={
        1: [MessageHandler(Filters.text, first_handler,
                           pass_user_data=True)],
    },
    fallbacks=[CommandHandler('stop', stop)]
)

dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
dispatcher.add_handler(conv_handler)

updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.Filters.command), the `MessageHandler(Filters.text, ...)` is handling **all** text messages, including the /stop command. However, fallbacks are only being triggered if none of the above handlers were able to deal with the message.

You may exclude commands from the MessageHandler:

```
MessageHandler(
    Filters.text & (~ Filters.command),
    first_handler,
)
```

The syntax for combining filters is documented [here](https://pythontelegramrobot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/telegram.ext.filters.html#telegram.ext.filters.BaseFilter).

Comment: Do you mean to add this exclusion to <MessageHandler> in <states>? It won't work, unfortunately. "Unresolved attribute reference 'mergedFilter' for class 'Filters' " and "Unresolved attribute reference 'InvertedFilter' for class 'Filters'" errors

Comment: I edited my answer, did you use the latest version? Just replace your MessageHandler as you said.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now. As far as I understand, we just excluded commands "/start", "/stop", "/anything" from MessageHandler for def. first_handler? Right?

Comment: I'd like to add that `pass_user_data` is deprecated and won't have any effect as OP is using the context-based API introduced in v12 of PTB.

Comment: @Ivan That is correct. You could instead exclude the single message "/stop" only when using ```Filters.text & (~ Filters.text(["/stop"]))``` as your filter.

Comment: @CallMeStag So I could just delete pass_user_data?